# plant.set_velocities(...) not affecting plant

Tags: c++, eigen, drake

I am trying to set the initial angular rotation for my robot plant. The model consists of a RigidBody with four legs attached. Gravity is disabled, such that there should be no forces acting on the plant.

```
  unique_ptr<Context<double>> root_context = diagram->CreateDefaultContext();
  Context<double>& plant_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(root_context.get());  

  
  Eigen::VectorXd velocity = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(plant.num_velocities());
  velocity[4] = 10;
  velocity[1] = 10;

  plant.SetVelocities(&plant_context, velocity);

  /*plant.SetFreeBodySpatialVelocity(&plant_context, 
  plant.GetBodyByName("main_body",body_indices[0]),
  SpatialVelocity<double>{ Vector3d(5.0, 5.0, 0.0), Vector3d(10.0, 10.0, 0.0)});*/
```

I tried using both plant.SetVelocities(...) and plant.SetFreeBodySpatialVelocity(...), but the body does not move in either cases. I have tried putting every state to 10, and not attaching the legs to the robot.

Comment: I suspect that you *are* successfully setting the velocity in the context (those lines look reasonable), but then are not using the `root_context` you've allocated here in your simulation?  When you allocate a `Simulator`, it will create it's own context unless you pass one in.  Perhaps you can confirm?

Comment: Thank you, @RussTedrake! Passing the root_context to the simulator did the trick, but I had to input it using std::move()

Simulator<double> simulator(*diagram, std::move(root_context));